# game character moves out of screen limit

Tags: coronasdk

In my game character should move from left to right (using accelerometer), and I've set the limit on the move that the character can make (i think). However it happens quite a few times, when the character has moved to it's right limit for example, and i tried tilting the phone right some more, somehow the character can move out of the permitted limit and goes missing in oblivion. here's my code -

```
display.setStatusBar (display.HiddenStatusBar)
-- Hides the status bar

local physics = require ("physics")
physics.start()
physics.setGravity(0,0)
-- start physics engine and set the gravity (I'm using 0 to start, you might want to change this.)

background = display.newImage ("back.jpg")
local floor = display.newRect(320, 0, 1, 480)
local lWall = display.newRect(0, 480, 320, 1)
local rWall = display.newRect(0, -1, 320, 1)
local ceiling = display.newRect(-1, 0, 1, 480)

staticMaterial = {density=2, friction=.3, bounce=.4}
physics.addBody(floor, "static", staticMaterial)
physics.addBody(lWall, "static", staticMaterial)
physics.addBody(rWall, "static", staticMaterial)
physics.addBody(ceiling, "static", staticMaterial)
-- Sets the background

collector = display.newImage ("ms_throw.png")
collector.x = 10
collector.y = 10
physics.addBody(collector, {friction = 1.0, bounce=0.6})
-- Adds the collector and adds physics to the collector

-- Create the table to throw eggs
local vertPost = display.newRect(0, 400, 160, 10)
vertPost:setFillColor(33, 33, 33)
local horizPost = display.newRect(160, 400, 10, 155)
horizPost:setFillColor(33, 33, 33)
physics.addBody(vertPost, "static", staticMaterial)

-- Put a character on top of the table
thrower = display.newImage ("mr_throw.png")
thrower.x = 230
thrower.y = 460

local motionx = 0
local motiony = 0

local function onAccelerate( event )
motiony = 35 * event.yGravity
end
Runtime:addEventListener ("accelerometer", onAccelerate)

local function movecollector (event)
collector.x = collector.x + motionx
collector.y = collector.y - motiony
end
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", movecollector)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your movecollector function, try using `body:applyForce( xForce, yForce, bodyX, bodyY )` rather than updating the x and y positions.

Comment: what should be the value for xForce, yForce, bodyX, bodyY ?

Comment: xForce and yForce will be some variation of your motionx/y properties. bodyX and bodyY will be the x/y properties of your "collector" object (collector.x, collector.y)